# Finding different groups between 0 and 1000 that are in the file

Tags: linux, sorting, awk, grep, uniq

I have a file with 7 fields separated with a `:`. In field 4 it has the group number. I want to display the group numbers within 0-1000. If there is a duplicate, I only want to print one copy of it along with the other group numbers that don't have a duplicate.

I have to use `grep`, `awk`, `sort` and `uniq`.

I don't know the first place to start. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Start with a file with 7 fields separated with a whitespace and use awk to print only column 4.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F: '$4>=0 && $4<=1000 && !a[$4]++' file
```

conditions are trivial, the array indexed by $4 will have nonzero value for the duplicates and not printed, only the first value of duplicates will have zero (before the `++` increment) value and printed.